# Existence of primitive permutation group one of whose arc stabilisers is normal in the point stabiliser

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a primitive permutation group with point stabiliser $G_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. For $\beta\ne\alpha$, by an arc stabiliser we mean $G_{\alpha\beta}=G_\alpha\cap G_\beta$ and an edge stabiliser we mean $G_{\{\alpha,\beta\}}$, the stabiliser of the set $\{\alpha,\beta\}$. Note that $G_{\{\alpha,\beta\}}\ge G_{\alpha\beta}$.

**My question is:** can an arc stabiliser $G_{\alpha\beta}\ne 1$ be normal in $G_\alpha$?

This is impossible if $G_{\{\alpha,\beta\}}> G_{\alpha\beta}$. In this case, there exists $g\in G$ such that $\alpha^g=\beta$ and $\beta^g=\alpha$. It follows that $g\in N_G(G_{\alpha\beta})$. Note that $G_\alpha$ is maximal in $G$ and $G_{\alpha\beta}$ cannot be normal in $G$ (otherwise $G_{\alpha\beta}$ will be in the kernel of this action), the normaliser $N_G(G_{\alpha\beta})=G_\alpha$. This gives a contradiction: $g\in G_\alpha$ but $\alpha^g=\beta\ne \alpha$.

I think there might exist an example in the case when $G_{\{\alpha,\beta\}}=G_{\alpha\beta}$. However, by a quick check with Magma there is no such primitive permutation group $G$ with $|G|\le 300$.

Added: I asked the same question here in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372398/existence-or-non-existence-of-primitive-permutation-group-one-of-whose-arc-sta) one day after this was asked.

Comment: I checked that there are no examples of degree at most 150. Here's another little observation: 
Suppose that $(\alpha,\beta)$ is in the same orbit under $G$ as $(\gamma,\alpha)$. Then, under your hypothesis, $G_{\alpha\gamma}$ is self-normalising in $G_\alpha$. This is Theorem 18.6 in Wielandt's Permutation Group, but it's just a little exercise. In particular, this shows that $G_\alpha/G_{\alpha\beta}$ cannot be a $p$-group.

Comment: I have checked the complete primitive groups database up to degree 4095, and there are no examples, so perhaps there are none. But it might turn out that, like the Sims conjecture, this would require the classification of finite simple groups to prove it. You could try asking it on MathOverflow.

Comment: It could be useful to rule out most families of primitive actions given by the O'Nan–Scott theorem. For instance, for the $G$ acting on $G/H$ where $G=H\ltimes V$, $V$ elementary abelian $p$-group with irreducible faithful $H$-action, this cannot happen (the condition that some pair stabilizer is normal in a stabilizer forces $H$ to act freely on $V-\{0\}$, making the pair stabilizer trivial.